# Topics in particle cosmology

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology

I am interested in learning more about this interdisciplinary approach.

1) What are some of the top questions in particle cosmology (e.g nature of dark matter, inflationary structure, topological defects in the universe)?

2) Who are some of the top researchers in this field?

3) Recommended review papers (on arxiv, for instance) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe You should ask this at theoretical physics SE http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions to get an answer ...

Comment: Appears to be a "make-la-list" question.